# MYSQL query to get the old records even after the update

Tags: mysql

I would like to know the previous updated value in my MYSQL DB.

```
si.no   cus_name     date      status
  1      JOHN     2012-05-02   active
```

---

```
  1      PAUL     2012-05-02   active ( not a new record just an 1st-update )

  1      JOSE     2012-05-02   active  ( not a new record just an 2nd-update )
```

Now i would like to get the cus_name value `"JOHN"` when i update the name with `"PAUL"` same with `"JOSE"` should give the value as `"PAUL"`.

Kindly suggest me a query for the same.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: how do you know that the record is the first update or second, or etc?

Comment: first time the records will be inserted from the register page , here i wont search for old records... i want to get the old records thru separete query which i handle in another module. Thanks for your interest John. :)

Comment: @Harry you should use trigger for these options it would be handy to solve your prob

Comment: Stranger, Thanks for your comment, ya that would do it.but i was expecting in a query , any way thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access previous values you have two options.

1. Design the table with a version number and timestamp columns, such that you can always fetch the most current version, and any prior version of the row.  You have to change update operations to be inserts, possibly in your application code or with triggers.  If the table gets frequent updates this could cause the table to grow quite large.
2. Use a second table to store previous versions of updated rows. That table will need a version number (and possibly update timestamp). This approach has the advantage that the primary table with "current" data will not experience unbounded growth as the updates accumulate.  This could also be accomplished with a trigger or in your application.

Which one you choose will depend on the frequency of updates as well as the frequency of access to "old" records.

Comment: That great to hear.but what you pointed out seems to have separate table isn't it ? just looking to sort out without creating new. Thanks for your time and patience man.

Answer (score 1):

you should need to add one more colum in db and insert the current time using time(); function. so you can easily identify which one is older. another solution is change the structure of date in database from `date` to `DATETIME` so you can easily check..

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer_record` (
`si.no` int(11) NOT NULL,
`cus_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
`status` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Yeah, even i thought of maintaining the separate column to store the previous values.... but thought it would be even better if we can do it what i have. since already the the table has been overloaded.Thanks for your time MIT :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple way, add an auto_increment field to the table. To get the last value simply select, order by the auto_increment field in descending order limit 1.

Comment: I think u totally misunderstood my question. Any way thanks for your comment and time.